# Generic way to run existing executables in parallel

Tags: c++, c, language-agnostic, cross-platform, parallel-processing

I'm trying to think of a solution regarding a way to run existing executables in parallel. What I came up so far is making a wrapper that puts the specified executable in a queue (managed by a 'server'). The problem that I have is when I need to run multiple executables whose output is another's executable input.

**Example:**

I have an executable **A** whose output is a file (an image). 
I have another executable **B** whose input is a list of files (consider it creates thumbnails from **A**'s images, stores them in an archive, etc)

The question is: is there a way to make the **B** executable wait for the multiple **A** processes to finish?

Is there a standard way of doing this? I'm interested in the concept and if it is possible, rather than the language. It would be nice if the solution is cross platform but for the moment I don't have any solutions so feel free to share your ideas. I assume this will be somehow done in C/C++ as it requires some low level interaction.

**SIMPLIFIED:**

> ---

I have some executables (**A**) running in background and another executable (**B**) that uses their output as input. How can I block the execution of **B** until all the needed input files are available.

**NOTE:**
executables **A** run continuously on the machine but some of the input files are 'collected' periodically by **B**.

> ---

Thanks for any suggestions,

Iulian

Comment: There are a number of methods that can be used for inter-process communication.  [Here are a few.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree with IPC (I'm using that) but imagine that I run everything asynchronously via the mentioned 'server' and while the **B** executable is run others **A** executables are run. The problem is how do I 'block' **B** to execute until all input files are done?

Comment: **B** waits until it receives a signal from each of the child processes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, but as I said in my edit there are many child processes **A** and not every one delivers an input file for **B**. For example **B** can wait for 3 files and I have 5 **A** processes running, from which only 3 are creating input for **B** ...

Comment: You have to make **B** aware of all potential inputs from **A**'s.The easiest way to do that would probably be to pass command line arguments into **B** when you execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about a program that does this for you, [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) will do this for you.  You can set it to run on a cron job, or whatever you think you need.  We frequently run it from scripts to rewrite large amounts of text (or code) and fully utilize all of the machine's cores to do the job.  Frequently you can use Parallel along with scripts and sed / awk to get whatever you really need done.  I'm not entirely clear if you want to do this programmatically, however, so perhaps this isn't the best answer.

Comment: Running executables in parallel is a solved issue. But the other issue is synchronisation - to know when all 'depending' tasks have finished their processing phase. ---> the output files are guaranteed to exist ----> we can execute the binary depending on the output files.

Comment: That's what the make tool actually does. It's a generic tool, not just usable for compiling source code. state your dependencies correctlly, and make -j10 will run up to 10 processes in parallel when it can, and dependant targets will be run when those are finished. If it's as simple as having 1 process wait for multiple other process, a simple shell script will do: `for i in $(seq 10) ; do ./A & done wait ; ./B`

Comment: @nos yes, I know about make but in my case every executable finishes instantly (is run in background) and I don't know when the files are available. As I mentioned: I cannot wait for all processes because other **A** executables are not creating files used for **B**'s input ...

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to write anything:

[whenjobs](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/whenjobs/) is a cron replacement that not only allows you to specify jobs (potentially repeating) but also takes into account job dependencies:

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to use synchronization primitives, e.g. semaphores or barriers. However, this does not (only) depends on the language, but requires interaction with the platfrom (usually the OS).

However, the C++11 standard deploys a standardized threading model at library level.

Comment: it's not about threading -> I'm running existing executables ... the problem is waiting for the input to be available.

Comment: That is exactly that, what it is about. Threads are lightweight processes, you asking for 'real' processes, but the principle is the same. Use semaphores or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do it is to create a dependency tree, where child nodes depend on the parent nodes' outputs.  Then you can run each level of your tree in parallel.

For example:

P1's output goes to P2 and P3

P2's output goes to P4

P3's output goes to P4.

Then your tree looks like:

```
                     P1
                    /  \
                   P2  P3
                    \  /
                     P4
```

You have to run P1 first, P2 and P3 can be run in parallel and then P4 gets executed last.

Also it doesn't have to be C++, any old language would do the trick I'm sure

**EDIT:**
If you don't know when the previous job ends to start the next one you could set a loop that at every set interval of time goes through all the executables you want to run and checks that the files they need are created, if they are they run it, otherwise wait until the next iteration and check again.

A general idea (in C++) could go something like:

```
    struct Job
    {
      bool PreconditionsSatisfied();
      void Run();
    };

    std::vector<Job> jobs;

    //Fill up with appropriate info

    while(jobs.size() != 0)
      {
        for(int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++)
          {
             if(jobs[i].PreconditionsSatisfied())
              {
                //start new thread and run job
                jobs.erase(jobs.begin() + i);
                i--;
              }
          }
        sleep(TIME_INTERVAL);
      }
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately in my case P2 & P3 are executed in parallel (asynchronously) and P4 doesn't know when their output exists and is launched before that happens ---> error. I'm executing asynchronously because it is faster ...

Answer (score 0):

People routinely use make (or other build tools) to accomplish this, because that's exactly what these tools do: build things based on inputs with dependencies, and most - certainly make - can do this in parallel.  If you have an executable that makes a series of images from (say) data files, and you have two batches of them to process (say by appending them to each other), and you have to run the second executable on each batch separately, then the following Makefile

```
execA=./gnuplotwrapper
execB=convert

all: figure1.png figure2.png

# convert txt files to png files using a gnuplot script "gnuplotwrapper"

%.png: %.txt
    $(execA) $^ $@

# take two figures and append them using imagemagick's "convert"

figure1.png: data1.png data2.png
    $(execB) $^ +append $@

figure2.png: data3.png data4.png
    $(execB) $^ +append $@

clean:
    rm -f *.png
```

will use executable A to generate the image files from the data files, and executable B to process batches of the image files.  By running this with (say) `make -j 4`, make will attempt to use up to 4 processes in parallel to build the final result (here, figure1.png and figure2.png).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run different executables on a system, I think the cleanest solution is to use a [scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler#Batch_queuing_for_HPC_clusters). Slurm or TORQUE should be nice choices.

Further, the specific feature you asked for is sometimes reffered as multi-step job scheduling . If not natively supported by the scheduler it's quite easy to achieve the same result with a series of jobs that, if successful, will submit their continuation.